# App Store build version and TestFlight build version different which version will appear on app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, version, appstore-approval

I have many versions on TestFlight uploaded (e.g., 1.7.1, 1.7.2, etc.). Now I want to upload the app to [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_%28iOS%29) with version 1.0, so if I select the version from TestFlight, e.g. version 1.7.1, which version will appear on App Store?

[image]

I am thinking that above the image description is valid when you directly upload the app from Xcode. But due to this, I got some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure version of the build and version you are creating on App Store both are same.

It will show with version you add in textbox, which shows in image.

[image]

#### Information section

[image]

#### Version History

[image]

Comment: Means if I have select version 1.7.1 with build number 13 for upload. On app store it will show the version which I enter in text field like shown in image.

Comment: See AppStore app in iPhone device -> open one application-> See Information section of the application & Version History section. You will get idea.

Comment: version history will show in iTunes connect. So user will always knows or able to see it will be 1.0 version of the app right ?

Comment: Version history you are talking about in iTune connect. On app store in version history it will be list of versions we upload the updated builds on app store. right?

Comment: Finally, it will show all the version which you have entered while uploading on AppStore. It doesn't matter which build version in XCode or TestFlight.

Comment: Sorry for more confusion.

Comment: I will accept answer once i does uploading app on app store. Thanks Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: @python Welcome !!

Comment: Yes, You have to match both version.

Comment: @ Bhadresh Mulsaniya You creating confusion. Question is about TestFlight build and xcode build. Please state your answer clearly. Please mention in your ans about which build your talking about. Otherwise I have to down vote your ans.

Comment: Store version number and version number which contains your build whether it's Xcode build/TestFlight build must be same.

Comment: @python Image which you have added in question states that AppStore version number and Xcode build version is same. At the end TestFlight build is also created from Xcode.