# Do I need to change the build number and version of TestFlight before submitting for review the same testflight as 1.0 (version) and 1 (build number)?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect, release

I am going to push a new build in [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS)).

But the TestFlight build number is 53 and the build version is 1.39.

Can I send the same version for the review in App Store? After app review, while going to live, does it show the build as 53 and build version is 1.39?

How can I add the build 1.0.0 or any valid version?

Comment: Have a look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607273/app-store-build-version-and-testflight-build-version-different-which-version-wil

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to change the numbers. You must use the same or higher numbers.

You cannot go from 1.39 to 1.0.0, that is downward. You must keep 1.39 and use the same build, or go up. You’ve made a bad mistake using 1.39, the next highest number is 1.40. These are version strings, not decimals! And they can only ever go up.  I suggest you jump to 2.0.0 and be more careful in future.

The other number, 53, is not user facing. It can never go down either, but that doesn’t matter as only you and Apple can see it. You can just keep incrementing it as desired. But the 1.39 or whatever will show on the App Store.

Comment: But here I have changed the build version to 1.o and build number as 1. My build successfully updated in testflight with version 1.0. So I added the binary(1.0) to submit for review. Can you explain another thing? My app get rejected with need more information. Shall I need to submit it again after filling the information?

Comment: Re *"These are version strings, not decimals!"*: Can you make it less ambiguous (as a normal string compare would (presumably) not work as intended)?